# How to add company icon in Drupal 8 toolbar

Tags: drupal

I am trying to add company icon in the toolbar (the bar with the black background).

Anybody has an idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can take look at what the core toolbar module's [toolbar.icons.theme.css](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!themes!stable!css!toolbar!toolbar.icons.theme.css/8.2.x).

```
.toolbar-icon-webtrack-update-reminder-main:before {
  background-image: url(path/to/svg);
}
.toolbar-icon-webtrack-update-reminder-main:active:before,
.toolbar-icon-webtrack-update-reminder-main.is-active:before {
  background-image: url(path/to/svg);
}
```

[This may solve your issue](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/198778/add-icon-to-menu-link-that-has-system-admin-as-a-parent)

Comment: Hmm, this is great, but how could I put these changes in module?

Comment: Is there  core/themes/stable/css/toolbar/toolbar.icons.theme.css file? You can add css there. If answer helped you, please vote it.